# How to fine tune an object detection model for custom data and classes using Detectron2?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, detectron

I have a pre-trained model weight (as `.pth`) and it's configuration (as `.yaml`) and I want to fine-tune this model on my downstream task. The only problem is that **I have 1 class while the pre trained model has 5 classes** and when I have fine tuned my model with `Detectron2`, it gives me results for all the 5 classes instead of my 1 class. How can I deal with that scenario?

[This is the exact tutorial which I am following](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ammarnassanalhajali/layout-parser-model-training?scriptVersionId=77893632&cellId=13) but instead of training my classes on all 5 classes as `thing_classes= ['None','text', 'title', 'list', 'table', 'figure']`, I want to train just on one class as [`text`]. Author has answered but it did not help me as when I got the results during testing, I got results for all the 5 classes.

[Pre-trained Model Weight](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgy9c10wykk4lq4/model_final.pth?dl=1)
[Pre- trained Model Config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3b12qc4hc0yh4m/config.yml?dl=1)

**I have put `'category_id'` of every instance as 0** (because I have just 1 class).

Below is the code where I have registered the data and everything and **there is no problem with training, model trains well**

```
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor, DefaultTrainer

!wget -O ./faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.pth 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgy9c10wykk4lq4/model_final.pth?dl=1'

!wget -O ./faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3b12qc4hc0yh4m/config.yml?dl=1'

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1 # Just one class predictions

cfg.merge_from_file("./faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS= './faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.pth' # layout parser Pre trained weights

cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 4
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.0025
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 50 #adjust up if val mAP is still rising, adjust down if overfit
cfg.SOLVER.GAMMA = 0.05
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 4

cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = (Data_Resister_training,)
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg) 
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix it, but try inverting the `merge_from_file` call and the number of classes setting:

```
cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file("./faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1 # Just one class predictions
...
```

Maybe that parameter gets overwritten.

Comment: Okay. So you mean to say that my approach is correct and the configuration is getting overwritten somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in that place. Because you first set the number of classes and then merge the file. But I think it should be the other way around. Because if you open the file, you’ll see that inside the file is set `MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES`. Maybe, since it is set before in your script, before merging, after the merging your additional configuration is lost. I’m not entirely sure that this will fix it, but you should give it a try

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Thank you. Also, `cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS` should be loaded before  `cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES` or  after?

Comment: I'm not sure this one makes any difference. To be sure I would add `cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES` after.

Comment: Yes there isn't any clear instructions on where. Also, I need to turn off the `cfg.MODEL.MASK_ON` to `False` as I'm not using `Mask RCNN` so it's position would make a difference? I think that has to be done after the weights as they have done the same in [faster RCNN](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/configs/COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_50_C4_1x.yaml) vs [Mask RCNN](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_C4_1x.yaml) `yaml` files.

Comment: Yes, exactly, to configure my yaml I've followed as much as possible the files they had.